# zabbix interface wrong utilization of receive/sent

Tags: interface, monitoring, zabbix, cisco

I'm struggling with my interface item measurements Send and Received Bits.

The item of network interface for measure the send and receive bits I have added preprocessing with Custom multiplier to 8 [image].

When I using the snmpwalk to get the current interface traffic, I got the value is:

IF-MIB::ifHCOutOctets.2 = Counter64: 11057731246261

But back to zabbix web monitoring system, it show only have [image] for this interface sent, did anyone have these problem or findings can be fix it can provide?

Answer (score 0):

My advice for you is to get inspired by the default zabbix templates and how things are set in them.

[image]

do not forget to set a correct unit for your item - these can make difference how the final value of the item is calculated:

https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/5.0/en/manual/config/items/item

as far as  post-processing goes it seems to be set correcly in your case.

Your item may be incorrecly detected as `unixtime` and therefore you see date instead of `bytes per second` so I advise to put in `bps` in the `Units` field.